# Serenity+JBehave - can't start tests in IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I'm using Serenity with JBehave.
For configuration what driver to start I use "serenity.properties" file and standard serenity properties for driver

> **webdriver.driver=iexplorer
>
>   webdriver.chrome.driver=Drivers/chromedriver.exe
>
>   webdriver.ie.driver=Drivers\IEDriverServer.exe**

When I set webdriver.driver property to "firefox" or "chrome" everything works fine and test are run as expected.
But when I try to use IE browser is not opened and I get an exception:

```
ERROR net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade - FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:209)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:142)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:133)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:103)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.openIgnoringHtmlUnitScriptErrors(WebDriverFacade.java:178)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.get(WebDriverFacade.java:173)<br>
    at ua.dataart.pages.LoginPage.openBaseUrl(LoginPage.java:59)<br>
    at ua.dataart.steps.serenity.RegistrationSteps.regPage_is_opened(RegistrationSteps.java:20)<br>
    at ua.dataart.steps.serenity.RegistrationSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$76672e1c.CGLIB$regPage_is_opened$3(<generated>)<br>
    at ua.dataart.steps.serenity.RegistrationSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$76672e1c$$FastClassByCGLIB$$dcecc188.invoke(<generated>)<br>
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:369)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:354)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:329)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:134)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:61)<br>
    at ua.dataart.steps.serenity.RegistrationSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$76672e1c.regPage_is_opened(<generated>)<br>
    at ua.dataart.steps.RegistrationAndLoginSteps.registrationPageIsOpened(RegistrationAndLoginSteps.java:54)<br>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)<br>
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)<br>
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:599)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$FineSoFar.run(PerformableTree.java:340)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableSteps.perform(PerformableTree.java:1072)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$AbstractPerformableScenario.performRestartableSteps(PerformableTree.java:938)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$NormalPerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:977)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:887)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.performScenarios(PerformableTree.java:811)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.perform(PerformableTree.java:784)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performCancellable(PerformableTree.java:416)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.perform(PerformableTree.java:387)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:291)<br>
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:265)<br>
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)<br>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)<br>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<br>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br>
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;** <br>
for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. <br>
The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html<br>
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:32)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:167)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:251)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:172)<br>
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebdriverInstanceFactory.newInternetExplorerDriver(WebdriverInstanceFactory.java:123)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.internetExplorerDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:564)<br>
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:188)<br>
    ... 37 more
Given user is on the registration page (FAILED)<br>
(net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver)<br>
```

I use same IE driver for my Selenium tests with some capability settings and it works fine.

All kinds of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your IEDriverServer.exe in PATH envvar. 
Also go to IE properties, security tab and enable or disable protected mode for all zones. All checkboxes must be checked or unchecked, no other variants.

Comment: Here is more details https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration